TM1 Rules DayNo - does it need a feeder?
I'm a bit confused with this formula as to why it would not add up to the "All Month" consolidation (Full Year). I'm not getting any data from any other cube or within the cube itself. So I don't know why it would need a feeder? I am thinking it needs a feeder because the line disappears when I suppress zero, which is usually a sign that it needs feeding.
What's up with this DayNo formula?
['Working Forecast' , '2070' , 'NZD' , 'Numeric' , 'Days in Month' ]= n: 
IF (!Month @<>'Dec' ,

DayNo  (!Year | '-' | Attrs( 'Month' , !Month , 'Next Cal Month String') | '-01')  -   DayNo (!Year | '-' | Attrs( 'Month' , !Month , 'Cal Month String') | '-01'),

 31) ;

